# redis - treat an empty list differently from a non-existent list?

Tags: python, redis

I haven't used redis in awhile and I'm porting pretty much all of my shared memory item code (aside from queues) in python multiprocessing to using a redis cache, and I needed to re-implement my locks. 
I found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20182448/3467349 - which suggests using `brpop` as a lock.

But this won't work if it's not possible to pre-instantiate all of the necessary lists.  Is there a special way to distinguish `nil` on a non-existent key and `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

There are no empty lists in Redis - once a list has no elements, it is deleted. You can verify that with the `EXISTS` command.

With `BRPOP`, however, you don't need to worry about that - even if the key doesn't exist the operation will continue until another client pushes something into that list or the timeout's expiration.

Comment: But that's the problem - if the list is empty (but have never been created) then the lock is technically free and yet `bprop` will block - since there is no way to distinguish between between an intentionally emptied list (to signify a `lock` - and one that has never been used). Also I found that the new version of `redis-py` has `lock` call so I'm trying that out.

Comment: In that case you should also look into Salvatore's redlock: http://redis.io/topics/distlock

Comment: I got `%timeit x = r.lock('bur'); x.acquire() ; x.release()` - 283 ms, `%timeit r.lpush('bur', 1); r.brpop('bur')` - 182ms. Which doesn't seem to be too different to be concerned.