# Caching JSON feed using PHP / ASPX

Tags: php, asp.net, caching

I'm creating a weather app using the wunderground api and since it limits the number of requests you can make per day / minute to 500 per day and 10 per minute I need to implement some form of caching using ASPX or PHP so that I remain within that limit.

Also, unfortunately I haven't got access to a database and I thought about generating a text file but I'm worried that it might try to fetch data in the middle of it being written and it cause errors.

What's the best way of caching this data for a single location while handling any concurrency issues that may arise?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET has cache which can be used for your purpose - see class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx.

Cache value for 10 minutes your can use this, then cached values automatically expires and actual values can be reloaded:

```
Cache.Insert(cache_key, value, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
  Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Retrive cached value by:

```
return Cache[cache_key];
```

For locking of the cached values (during reload) you can use lock keyword, more details can be found here: [Doing locking in ASP.NET correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578744/doing-locking-in-asp-net-correctly)

Comment: Thanks :) this worked perfectly. I decided against the locking though as redundant queries isn't as much of an issue as I thought.